# Transitioning Tensorflow backed Keras model to CoreML

Tags: ios, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras, coreml

I have a simple  Tensorflow backed Keras model that looks like this:

```
x_test = np.zeros((len(data) - max_samples, max_len, max_features), dtype=np.bool)
y_test = np.zeros((len(data) - max_samples, max_len, max_features), dtype=np.bool)

#... Populate x_test and y_test

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, batch_input_shape = (1, max_len, max_features), return_sequences=True, stateful=True))
model.add(Dense(max_features, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=RMSprop(lr=0.01),  metrics=['accuracy'])
```

which works fine in python when it predicts using input of shape `(1, max_len, max_features)`

However, when exported to CoreML model using `coremltools`, the input is totally different as seen here:

[image]

It asks for 3 arrays of doubles. Not sure why and what's the mapping to my inital shape.

**Update:**

I tried to feed in the model weights for `lstm_1_h_in` and `lstm_1_c_in` each iteration as follows, but alas the model return `nan` in this case.

```
Model* model = [Model new];
MLMultiArray* h = [[MLMultiArray alloc] initWithShape:@[@(neurons)]
                                             dataType:MLMultiArrayDataTypeDouble
                                                error:&error];
MLMultiArray* c = [[MLMultiArray alloc] initWithShape:@[@(neurons)]
                                         dataType:MLMultiArrayDataTypeDouble
                                            error:&error];
NSAssert(error == nil, assertMessage);

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < neurons; i++) {
    [h setObject:@(0) forKeyedSubscript:@[@(i)]];
    [c setObject:@(0) forKeyedSubscript:@[@(i)]];
}

ModelOutput* modelOutput = nil;
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < data.count; i++) {

    MLMultiArray* input = [[MLMultiArray alloc] initWithShape:@[@(modelZCount)]
                                                         dataType:MLMultiArrayDataTypeDouble
                                                            error:&error];
    NSAssert(error == nil, assertMessage);

    NSArray* key = @[data[i]];
    [input setObject:@(1) forKeyedSubscript:key];

    ModelInput* modelInput = [[ModelInput alloc] initWithInput1:input
                                                    lstm_1_h_in:h
                                                    lstm_1_c_in:c];

    modelOutput = [model predictionFromFeatures:modelInput error:&error];
    assertMessage = @"Failed to predict based on settings";
    NSAssert(error == nil, assertMessage);
    NSAssert(modelOutput != nil, assertMessage);

    h = modelOutput.lstm_1_h_out;
    c = modelOutput.lstm_1_c_out;
}

//modelOutput.output1 is @[nan, nan, nan, ...]
//same for lstm_1_h_in and lstm_1_c_in
```

Comment: batch size dim is removed?

Comment: I haven't used CoreML with RNNs before, but an LSTM cell takes as input the previous (or initial) hidden state. Those are the two extra inputs you see here. In Keras you can also provide these using the `initial_state` parameter. What happens if you remove `stateful=True`? Does your Core ML model still have those extra two inputs then?

Comment: @Matthijs Hollemans I was thinking about that, but I was thrown off the track by the fact that in Keras you don’t have to do it when using predict. If I remove stateful, things are exactly the same. Actually, now that I’m thinking about it, make sense, instead of sending the time you’re sending the previous state.  I will try it and report back .

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans I tried it, unfortunately, output is always `nan`. Upated my answer.

Comment: My bad, I was not initializing the multi array to 0. Apparently they come initialized with garbage values.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans Can you make your comment into an answer, you put me on the right track, would like to reward you with some internet points.